# How can I generate a list of linked data with SQL

Tags: aggregation

I've got a table with this kind of data:

[image]

I would like to this result with a query:

[image]

Do you have any idea how to achieve this ?

I know that I need to use XMLAGG somewhere to get the final concatenation but I don't know how to group A B C and D (the rule is because 1 has A & B, 2 has B & C then A is linked to C, etc)

Thanks

Comment: What's so special about `E` that it needs to be on a new line? If you just want a list of the names, use `distinct()`. `select distinct(name) from table`

Comment: E is linked to no one else (in a transitiv way). Others are all 'linked'  1 (A -> B), 2 (B -> C) then (A -> B -> C) and finally 3 (C -> D) then (A -> B -> C -> D)